# program that prints input in bash

Tags: bash

I am new to bash and I struggling with a program. I want to write a program that first asks for user input and afterwards prints the words with an \n(blank line) between them. The last echo contains the amount of characters that is written. Also the output can only contain the words and no digits. E.g:

```
Input: hallo1 user2 Pete4
Ouput: hallo
       user
       Pete
       13 Characters
```

This is my code for the time beeing.

```
echo Typ one or multiple words: 

read varname
arr=( "${arr[@]}" "$varname" )
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done

echo ${arr[@]}
# printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: This is missing the current output and the difference from what is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach in plain `bash` without using an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Type one or multiple words on a line:'

read -r
words_without_digits=${REPLY//[0-9]}
line_without_blanks=${words_without_digits//[[:blank:]]}
printf '%s\n' $words_without_digits
echo "${#line_without_blanks} Characters"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Works for me. I added in the for the sentence to remove the digits.
And after the for, I first remove the spaces between the names and then I count the total of characters using the # in ${#aux}. I added the parameter -n in the first echo too, just to break the line with the second one.

```
echo Type one or multiple words: 

read varname
arr=( "${arr[@]}" "$varname" )
for i in "${arr[@]//[[:digit:]]/}"; do
    echo -n "$i"
done

aux=$(echo "${i}" | sed "s/ //g")
echo " " ${#aux} " Characters"
```

Comment: You should explain what is wrong in OPs code and for which reason, and why your code gives the expected result.

Comment: The OP wrote: `"and afterwards prints the words with an \n(blank line) between them"`. This script writes the words on the same line.

Comment: luckily the code from you (Nejat Aydin) does the exact thing I asked for, so thank you for that. Tesekkur ederim abi. Çok yardimci oldun. Thank you both. You guys really helped me out! But that one thing (printing the words on a blank line), I couldn't find out with José's code. So maybe you can help me out?

Comment: Is similar. I just posted a new answer with the correction. You needed just to change the echo by printf.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Type one or multiple words: 

read varname
arr=( "${arr[@]}" "$varname" )
for i in "${arr[@]//[[:digit:]]/}"; do
    printf '%s\n'  $i
done

aux=$(echo "${i}" | sed "s/ //g")
echo ${#aux} " Characters"
```